# Removing numbers and characters from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

If a user clicks on a tag, right now it recognizes the full text (numbers and characters).

returns `Popular Tag %82`

I've tried:

```
$tag.click(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var text = $this.text();
  var num = text.parseInt();
  num.remove();
  alert(text)
});
```

Doesn't do the trick for numbers. So how would I get just the letters? Ie: ignoring BOTH numbers and special characters(%)

[Fiddle here!](http://jsfiddle.net/cyEzC/11/) Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a regex:

```
var s = "ABCblahFoo$%^3l";
var letters = s.replace(/[^A-Za-z]+/g, '');
```

- the `[]` represents a character (or a number of different possible characters)
- the `^` means all characters **EXCEPT** the ones defined in the brackets
- `A-Z` equals capital letters
- `a-z` equals lowercase letters

So... Replace every character that is NOT a letter with the empty string.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cyEzC/13)

Comment: +1, but I would add a `+` to the `[^A-Za-z]` so that if there are consecutive characters to be removed, they can be  can be removed in one go, as opposed to one by one.

Comment: @jahroy You're welcome, after seeing you on the other regex question I enjoyed a cruise through some of your answers. :)

Comment: @zx81 - Likewise. I've enjoyed that [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23839481/find-out-the-position-where-a-regular-expression-failed) as well (though I'm out of my league) and hope the dialogue continues some more!

Comment: @jahroy He does sound quite competent and I too would like to hear from him—the convo could be interesting and I'm sure I'd learn something. Nice being in touch, wishing you a relaxing weekend.

Answer (score 0):

**the above answer will remove spaces from the string.**

```
var str = "Hello^# World/";
str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "");
```

use this. Simply add space after **A-Z** in the regex.