# Find out the position where a regular expression failed

Tags: javascript, regex, lexical-analysis

I'm trying to write a lexer in JavaScript for finding tokens of a simple domain-specific language. I started with a simple implementation which just tries to match subsequent regexps from the current position in a line to find out whether it matches some token format and accept it then.

The problem is that when something doesn't match inside such regexp, the whole regexp fails, so I don't know which character exactly caused it to fail.

Is there any way to find out the position in the string which caused the regular expression to fail?

INB4: I'm not asking about debugging my regexp and verifying its correctness. It is correct already, matches correct strings and drops incorrect ones. I just want to know programmatically where exactly the regexp stopped matching, to find out the position of a character which was incorrect in the user input, and how much of them were OK.

Is there some way to do it with just simple regexps instead of going on with implementing a full-blown finite state automaton?

Answer (score 34):

**Short answer**

> There is no such thing as a "position in the string that causes the
>   regular expression to fail".

However, I will show you an approach to answer the reverse question:

> At which token in the regex did the engine become unable to match the
>   string?

**Discussion**

In my view, the question of `the position in the string which caused the regular expression to fail` is upside-down. As the engine moves down the string with the left hand and the pattern with the right hand, a regex token that matches six characters one moment can later, because of quantifiers and backtracking, be reduced to matching zero characters the next—or expanded to match ten.

In my view, a more proper question would be:

> At which token in the regex did the engine become unable to match the
>   string?

For instance, consider the regex `^\w+\d+$` and the string `abc132z`.

The `\w+` can actually match the entire string. Yet, the entire regex fails. Does it make sense to say that the regex fails at the end of the string? I don't think so. Consider this.

Initially, `\w+` will match `abc132z`. Then the engine advances to the next token: `\d+`. At this stage, the engine backtracks in the string, gradually letting the `\w+` give up the `2z` (so that the `\w+` now only corresponds to `abc13`), allowing the `\d+` to match `2`.

At this stage, the `$` assertion fails as the `z` is left. The engine backtracks, letting the `\w+`, give up the `3` character, then the `1` (so that the `\w+` now only corresponds to `abc`), eventually allowing the `\d+` to match `132`. At each step, the engine tries the `$` assertion and fails. Depending on engine internals, more backtracking may occur: the `\d+` will give up the 2 and the 3 once again, then the `\w+` will give up the c and the b. When the engine finally gives up, the `\w+` only matches the initial `a`. Can you say that the regex "fails on the "3"? On the "b"?

No. If you're looking at the regex pattern from left to right, you can argue that it fails on the `$`, because it's the first token we were not able to add to the match. Bear in mind that there are other ways to argue this.

Lower, I'll give you a screenshot to visualize this. But first, let's see if we can answer the other question.

**The Other Question**

Are there techniques that allow us to answer the other question:

> At which token in the regex did the engine become unable to match the
>   string?

It depends on your regex. If you are able to slice your regex into clean components, then you can devise an expression with a series of optional lookaheads inside capture groups, allowing the match to always succeed. The first unset capture group is the one that caused the failure.

Javascript is a bit stingy on optional lookaheads, but you can write something like this:

```
^(?:(?=(\w+)))?(?:(?=(\w+\d+)))?(?:(?=(\w+\d+$)))?.
```

In PCRE, .NET, Python... you could write this more compactly:

```
^(?=(\w+))?(?=(\w+\d+))?(?=(\w+\d+$))?.
```

What happens here? Each lookahead builds incrementally on the last one, adding one token at a time. Therefore we can test each token separately. The dot at the end is an optional flourish for visual feedback: we can see in a debugger that at least one character is matched, but we don't care about that character, we only care about the capture groups.

1. Group 1 tests the `\w+` token
2. Group 2 seems to test `\w+\d+`, therefore, incrementally, it tests the `\d+` token
3. Group 3 seems to test `\w+\d+$`, therefore, incrementally, it tests the `$` token

There are three capture groups. If all three are set, the match is a full success. If only Group 3 is not set (as with `abc123a`), you can say that the `$` caused the failure. If Group 1 is set but not Group 2 (as with `abc`), you can say that the `\d+` caused the failure.

**For reference: Inside View of a Failure Path**

For what it's worth, here is a view of the failure path from the RegexBuddy debugger.

[image: RegexBuddy Debug]

Comment: Excellent discussion.

Comment: @JoeFrambach Thanks very much. :) I wasn't done, just added answer to the other question, i.e. `At which token in the regex did the engine become unable to match the string?`

Comment: @SasQ Haven't heard from you on this question that I found very interesting.  Wondering if this answer helped in some way, or are you still wrestling with other approaches?

Comment: This is a beautifully articulated solution.  It's a shame the author hasn't accepted an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a negated character set [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#chracter-sets),

> ```
> [^xyz]
> [^a-c]
> ```
>
> A negated or complemented character set. That is, it matches anything
>   that is not enclosed in the brackets. You can specify a range of
>   characters by using a hyphen, but if the hyphen appears as the first
>   or last character enclosed in the square brackets it is taken as a
>   literal hyphen to be included in the character set as a normal
>   character.

`index` property of [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

> The returned Array has an extra input property, which contains the
>   original string that was parsed. In addition, it has an index
>   property, which represents the zero-based index of the match in the
>   string.

For example to log `index` where digit is matched for `RegExp` `/[^a-zA-z]/` in string `aBcD7zYx`

```js
var re = /[^a-zA-Z]/;
var str = "aBcD7zYx";
var i = str.match(re).index;
console.log(i); // 4
```

Comment: Note, [`String.prototype.search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) could also be used instead of `.match()`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to find out the position in the string which caused the regular expression to fail?

No, there isn't. A Regex either matches or doesn't. Nothing in between.

Partial Expressions can match, but the whole pattern doesnt. So the engine always needs to evaluates the whole expression:

Take the String `Hello my World` and the Pattern `/Hello World/`. While each word will match individually, the whole Expression fails. You cannot tell whether `Hello` or `World` matched - independent, both do. Also the whitespace between them is available.

Comment: Sure, I know how regexps work. But what you've said doesn't exclude what I'm asking. Notice that althought your regexp won't match the given string as a whole, there's still a certain character which makes it stop matching: there's `m` instead of the required `W` in the tested string. And that's what I want to know: the position of this particular character which has made the regexp to fail.

Comment: "I would say the match failed at the first character (the H‘) in this example" Why? "H" matches the part of the original regexp, as well as the whole "Hello " part. It only fails at "W", making the whole regexp fail. But I can still tell which character was the stumbling block.

Comment: @SasQ - If your regexes are always this simple (in which case there's no point in using a regex), then you could definitely get the answer you're after... All you have to do is match the first _n_ characters of the input against the first _n_ characters of the regex until there is no match... then _n_ is your failure point. However, I agree with zx81 that the "_point of failure_" is undefined once you start using real regexes that have any trace of usefulness or complexity.

Comment: My regexps are not always as simple as @dognose showed (and it's *his* example, not mine). But they're "simple" enough that a regular DFA would tell which character is a stumbling block. From automata theory we know that every regexp has an equivalent DFA. So if a DFA can tell me which character caused it to fail, I supposed a regexp engine could do it too. But it might depend on how the regexp engine is implemented (and this actually can make a big difference, as this article shows: http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html.

Comment: @SasQ - I am by no means a regex expert (and to be honest I actually had to google DFA), but from zx81's answer I gather that regex engines aren't able to answer your question and are implemented for speed and efficiency. In order to make them capable of answering your question, it seems like their implementation would have to be modified a great deal. I doubt the rest of the developers in the world want regex engines to become far less efficient just to answer your question.